# Asp.Net Core: Developer Exception Page for Cross-Site Requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, cross-domain

In our project we have an ASP.Net Core Web API backend and an Angular 5 frontend. In development mode, the Angular Page will run on its own server (using node, e.g. localhost:8000). Therefore, accessing a local instance of the API (e.g. localhost:57612) will be a cross-origin request.

CORS is correctly set up for the API, and in the successful case there are no issues. Also, I have enabled `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage()` in the API to get nice stack traces in case something goes wrong.

However, Asp.Net **only** returns the error details/stack trace (as HTML in the error response body) when the request was sent from the same origin (i.e. localhost:57612 in the example above). So in our development setup, we don't get this error response body, we get nothing.

I have not found a way to send the developer error page as response to an errored cross-orign request. In Asp.Net 4.5 + IIS, there was [a setting in IIS where one could control this behavior specifically](https://www.sherweb.com/blog/how-to-create-custom-error-pages-in-iis-7-5-with-asp-net/). Does anybody know how to control this behavior in Asp.Net core?

(I think I could implement a workaround in form of a custom ASP.Net error handler that will return all the details of the exception like the Developer Exception Page. But that's a bit silly, reimplementing this functionality.)

Comment: Update: I noticed that producing a custom HTTP response with status 500 does not do the trick. It seems __some__ middleware layer (IIS, Kestrel or Asp.Net?) throws away the response body of **all** HTTP responses with an error status code. :S

Comment: Update: I'm able to get my custom HTTP500 responses from other domains now. In order to make this work, I had to manually (re)set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header value (e.g. `*`). Somehow they're not there reliably when exceptions occur. This allows sending error bodies to other domains.